# Do you earn interest on unspent money?

Tags: bloons-td-5

Do you earn interest on your bank balance at the end of each wave? I know I get some amount of money after completing each wave, but I'm not sure if it's a fixed amount or variable, whether or not it increases as the game progresses or if it's tied to clearing a wave without letting any bloons through.

Comment: I removed the ios tag because it's not needed; platform tags are only used when the game mechanics differs from platform to platform.  I don't believe this is true for this one.

Comment: @Frank Thanks. I believe it's ChaseC's answer that was so far off from what I was expecting that threw me.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Do you mean the money in the bank tower or your own money?

Comment: @EpicGuy I mean the balance of all your money available to spend, at the end of each level. Not the money stored inside the Monkey Bank. When I asked this question, I didn't have the Monkey Bank unlocked yet. I wasn't even aware of it's existence.

Answer (score 3):

You earn 99 dollars + what round you are on at the end of each level. ***[SOURCE](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Money)***

So at the end of level 1, you'd earn 100 dollars. At the end of level 2, you'd earn 101 dollars.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Yeah I updated my answer to be more informative. I've been playing bloons since the first one came out. It's just knowledge that I knew from playing. I sources the wiki for you if you want to check it out.

Comment: Your link points to the wiki for the Banana Farm, but I'm asking about interest accruing at the end of a round even if you don't have any Banana Farms. I'm referring to the iOS version if that helps. I originally tagged my question as such, but Frank so helpfully removed it.

Comment: I've just confirmed that this answer is incorrect. 100 gold is given to the player at the end of every completed wave, and there is no additional interest unless a Monkey Bank exists.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer  The first line of the question, where it mentions "bank balance", is probably throwing people off.  A quick read certainly sounds like you're asking about Monkey Banks, which work as ChaseC described;  you're actually asking about general unspent money, which doesn't award interest.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Oh, then yes. My answer is incorrect if you don't mean the Monkey Bank. I'll update my answer for you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. According to your source, your answer looks slightly off. It seems that you earn $100 for round 1, $101 for round 2, etc. You're off by one.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer Whoops, happens sometimes when you don't look at what you're typing :D

Answer (score 3):

**In BTD5 you get $99 plus the number of the round, e.g. 100 for round 1, 101 for round 2 ...**

**[If you want interest in your money, look at the 2nd upgrade path of Banana Farms](http://bloons.wikia.com/wiki/Farm#BTD5)**

**Monkey Bank: $3570/$4200/$4535**

> The Monkey Bank will no longer drop bananas, but instead generates
>   money throughout the round, which is placed in your "bank account,"
>   separate from that of other Monkey Banks. Creates 450 money per round
>   plus 10% interest. You may withdraw this fund at any time, and the
>   bank will hold up to $5000. This will also lock the purchase of Banana
>   Republic or Banana Research Facility for this tower, however.
>   Purchasing More Bananas/Banana Plantation will make the bank generate
>   slightly more money (+ $40/$180 per round).

**Banana Investments Advisory: $4675/$5500/$5940**

> Increased money generated to 1000 per round, increases interest to
>   20%, and increases the maximum held at a time to $20000 per round.
>   Purchasing More Bananas/Banana Plantation will make the bank generate
>   slightly more money (+ $40/$180 per round). This upgrade is unlocked
>   at rank 36.